# Is levelling up inside a cave the same as levelling up at night?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

In Pokemon, using a Dusk Ball inside a cave gives the same effect as using it at night. **Does a cave also count as night when trying to meet evolution criteria?** For example to evolve an Eevee into an Umbreon, you need to level Eevee up whilst it's very happy and at night time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** - if you level up an Eevee inside a cave but during the daytime, it will still try to evolve into an Espeon rather than an Umbreon. **No matter how dark the environment, it's the time that counts for evolution.**

Comment: Wanna mark as accepted? :)

Comment: @Robotnik y'know, I'd totally forgotten to do so. Thanks for the reminder :)